# Connect to SQL Server 2008 with Windows Authentication without Active Directory

Tags: sql-server-2008, window, filestream, windows-authentication

I'm using filestream to stores data into my SQL Server, but from what I learn after some searching, is that filestream required the use of Integrated Security, so SQL authentication mode is not possible

How do I connect to the database using just win 7 or xp? I tried to add login to the database I cant seem to find other PC on the network other than the server

I do not own a windows server, so is it possible to create a login to a SQL Server 2008 from another computer without using a windows server?

Comment: `FILESTREAM` works fine on any version of Windows on which SQL Server is supported. So that's not the problem. Can you connect to SQL Server through Management Studio?

Comment: yes i can from the server itself, but i need to add users from other computer but not by using sql authentication mode, but using windows authentication mode, is it posible using only windows 7?

Comment: Ideally, you should be running in a domain to use win auth. However, I think it will work if you create the same user on both computers, with the same password.

Comment: from what i understand.. "domain" is not possible without a server, and windows authentication does not require password whatsoever

Comment: No, but you need to emulate a domain by creating the same user on both computers.

Comment: Btw, I'm not guaranteeing this will work. It's just about your only solution to use `Integrated Security` without the availability without a domain.

Answer (score 1):

I've just accomplished this very thing, so I thought I'd share what I did for anyone else who might run across this. I have one machine running Windows XP that is running my instance of SQL Server, and another machine on the network that needs access to the database. I was using SQL Server Authentication, but because I'm adding FILESTREAM support to the database, I now needed to switch to Windows Authentication.

In order to do this, I had to add an account on the XP machine that mirrors the account on the other machine (same username/password combination), then I had to add that user to SQL Server through SSMS.

To add the user to SQL Server, you have to use the name of the machine that's running the server as the domain name, so for instance, the name of my XP machine is XP_Pro, so the user name that I had to add to SQL Server was XP_Pro\Chris

Lastly, I had to change my connection string to:

```
Data Source=[database instance];Initial Catalog=[database name];Integrated Security=true
```

Notice that username and password are removed from the connection string

I hope this helps someone!